# Question on hold

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, on-hold

I guess I am just a little confused as to why [my question is put on hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140353/static-method-vs-new-class)

It says that my question was "too broad," but provides no other information.

This was my first question posted to Stack Exchange, so I appreciate any input you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

I would have voted as either Too Broad or Primarily Opinion Based.

This is not a specific question that can be easily answered ( not an x + x = ? ). It requires a possible answerer to know MUCH MUCH more about what you're actually doing and how it's going to be used in the future, etc. I think the first 2 comments under your question should have given you a clue...

Answers on Stack Overflow are expected to be the best possible solutions with justification why they are the best. In your case there is not best answer. There are just too many possible answers and this is not what Stack Overflow is all about.

You have to be more specific with your question... You have to narrow it to the point where you are either stuck or you are not sure of what choice to make next

For example

Convert the way your think - don't just ask "WHICH" is better...Consider your scenarios and keep asking yourself "WHY" something is better. Dig. Keep digging.

(*really stupid and simple examples but I hope this makes sense*)

Dont ask:

what is better: X + X = 5 or Y + Y + Y = 5

Dig, keep digging until your question becomes: WHY is X + X = 5 better than Y + Y + Y = 5? What cases? Under what circumstances? What is the part that you actually don't understand? What are your current assumptions and why do you think X + X is better than Y + Y + Y?

You really do need to ask your self those questions. Demonstrate to us that you do have some knowledge and try to present (if possible) your problem with an SSCCE example for others to reproduce.

Most of the time, asking yourself recursively and narrowing down your HUGE question to a small one you actually get to figure it all out yourself and you do not even need to ask a question on Stack Overflow. But there are cases, where you get stuck down the road and really need to get an insight - just remember: Stack Overflow should be the last place you come to with your problem. Your problem should be well described and specific.

There used to be a `too localized` reason to close a question but it's gone now. Try not to ask a very localized question like:

> In my program

Ok, what program? Is it even worth mentioning? If so, what is your program?

> I have a class "Team" that holds data for each object of team. Now I am trying to create an ArrayList of "Team" objects

This seems like a background/source info, how you got to your problem... Do you really think 2 sentences are enough to explain to us, *sitting on the other side of the cable*, where you coming from with your problem(further -> question)?

> I was wondering if it is better practice to create a new class to do so, or if I should just perform that task in a static method of "Team"

That, my friend, is your real question here - all other text can be dropped from your question. The code is not any useful here.

So your real problem description along with your question reads like

> In my program I have a class "Team" that holds data for each object of team. Now I am trying to create an ArrayList of "Team" objects, but I was wondering if it is better practice to create a new class to do so, or if I should just perform that task in a static method of "Team".

That's a 2, 3 sentences long question. How do you expect anyone to answer it without knowing **anything** about your problem, where it came from, what is your class going to do, etc..

Additionally, you have added:

> Edit: Primarily what I am asking here is whether the methods "dataExtract" and "hasTeam" (as shown in the code below) should be in their own class, or kept as static methods where they are.

That's alright, but tell us why do you think they should have their own class or not. What are the circumstances? How are they going to be used/re-used?

All the questions you need to ask yourself at first.

What you can do is edit your question, give background, explain how did you arrive at the stage of thinking you can solve something in 2 different ways, what do you think is better and why?

Before you go off editing your question, if you planning to hang around Stack Overflow, consider:

- getting familiar with our [Help-Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). There is a section about [`ASKING`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which explains what is on and off topic on Stack Overflow.

  - there is a little guide to help you learn [**how to ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Definitely a resource I try newcomers to get familiar with.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the complete on hold message appended to your question:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Then look at the links in the following paragraph.

Comment: Yes I have read that paragraph, as well as the related information in the help center. The help center suggested that I edit my post, and ask for more information on the Meta site. Both of which I have done. The only thing I did not do was flag for moderator attention. I did not do this because I do not believe that this issue is important enough to bother a moderator, and (as a new user) it is likely my own fault.

Comment: @Balthazarion Are you saying you do not understand the explanatory text and help, or that (you believe) it does not apply? You need to be much more specific here.